# how can i get int array from the string

Tags: java, arrays, string, numbers

i want to make the number array from the  StringTokenizer.

if there is text line 
  "  2345     "
i want to get array list [2,3,4,5] . so  first of all, 
i made Arraylist and get from the st token using the hasMoreToken

```
ArrayList argument_list = new ArrayList();
 while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    argument_list.add(Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken()));
}
int[] arguments = new int[argument_list.size()];
```

now i notice my argument_list get whole string to number "2345" not "2","3","4","5"
because there is no "split word" like " , "

maybe i can divide number use the  "/" 
but i think there is a way just split the String and get the number array even i don't know

is there way to split the token to array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
String s = "1234";
int[] intArray = new int[s.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   intArray[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `String#toCharArray`, and work with resulting `char[]`

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
char[] chars = "2345".toCharArray();
for (char c : chars) {
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c)));
}
```

You could also convert to char array in loop declaration, removing the need for `chars` variable

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (char c : "2345".toCharArray()) {
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c)));
}
```

Comment: why you need to convert to char array, if you could access every character from charAt api?

Comment: That's just another approach, you wouldn't need a char array but you'd need to use a counter in the for loop.

Comment: Yeah counter memory wise wont be expensive and internally toCharArray will create a new cloned copy of your characters within the String. So rather its not efficient and is not best in terms of memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
String s = "1234";
int[] intArray = new int[s.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    intArray[i] = parseInt(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
    String s="12345";
    String test[]=s.split("(?<!^)");

    int[] arguments = new int[test.length];
    for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        arguments[i]=Integer.parseInt(test[i]);
    }
```

The code splits the string into each character and later parses it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
String sTest = "1234";
int n = sTest.length();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

    int code = Integer.parseInt(sTest.substring(i, i+1));
    list.add(code);
    System.out.println(code);
}
System.out.println(list);
}
```